# Using the PHP date and time function to print a certain sentence

Tags: php, datetime

I'm in need of help with the PHP date/time function.

Using de date/time function, I need to print the following:

Today is 'current day', the 'number of day of month', in the year 'year'. Today is 'number of day of the year'. We still have 'number of days till end of year'.

Just can't get this working.. any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What have you tried so far?

Comment: What you've tried so far?

Comment: Sorry, still rather new here, will read that asap.<br> Got this so far: date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Paris");
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Europe/Amsterdam");
echo "Vandaag is het " . strftime("%A, %#d/%m/%Y. De tijd is %H:%M:%S");

Comment: `if(date('L')==1?$last=366-(date('z')+1):$last=365-(date('z')+1));
        echo "Today is ".date('D').", the ".date('d')." of the ".date('M').", in the year ".date('Y').". Today is ".(date('z')+1)." day of the year. We still have ".$last." days";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so there may be a better way to do this, but this is one way of getting all the different elements you asked for:

```
$d = new DateTime();
$currentDay = $d->format('l'); // Will give you the current day in full (i.e. Monday)
$dayOfMonth = $d->format('j'); // Will give you the current day of the Month
$year       = $d->format('Y'); // Will give you the current Year.
$dayOfYear  = ($d->format('z') + 1); // Starts at 0, so we add one to get the actual days past.
```

As for the days left, I reckon there is potentially a better way to do this, but here's a quick solution:

```
$daysInYear = 365;
if ($d->format('L') === 1) { // Returns 1 if leap year.
    $daysInYear = 366;
}
$daysLeft = $daysInYear - $dayOfYear;
```

That should give you all the variables you need to print out the statement you asked for.